# Http Azure Function without Function App Key in Azure Data Factory Linked Service

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Http trigger Azure Function. Now, I need to call this Azure Function in my ETL Pipeline. For this, I am creating a Azure Function Linked Service in Azure Data Factory.

While creating a Linked Service in ADF, Function App key is a Mandatory field. But I don't like to use the Function App Key. Instead, I can use the Managed Identity Access and Azure AD authentication of function app to connect from ETL pipelines.

[image]

Now, how to proceed further on creating a linked service without function app key.

I observed that Http Function url can be called in web activity same as we invoke APIs. But is there any difference in invoking function apps using Web Activity and Azure Function Activity.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) Azure Function linked supports only two authentication methods. Those are 'System-assigned managed identity' and 'anonymous'.

Azure function Linked service with anonymous authentication:

[image]

Azure function Linked service with System-assigned managed identity authentication:

[image]

As per above images Function App key is mandatory for Azure Function linked service. So, it is not possible to create Azure function linked service without Function App key. If you don't want to hard code it, you can make use of Azure key vault.

> I observed that Http Function url can be called in web activity same as we invoke APIs. But is there any difference in invoking function apps using Web Activity and Azure Function Activity.

As you said in web activity Function app is invoking by using function App URL. In Azure Function Activity Function activity function app is invoking by using Azure functions linked services as mentioned above.

Comment: This basically re-created the documentation you already linked to. For a question where the OP showed no work and only provided a high level requirement. Please don't answer questions where the OP doesn't provide any work of their own, and please don't re-create documentation that's already published. At best, post a doc link as a comment under the question.

Comment: ADF is purely a configuration and I am not sure what is the work need to show here. If you need something, please ask me and I will revert. Stack Overflow is a forum where anyone can look answers for their questions. Coming to my question, without doing any work, how can I ask the detailed question. Anyhow, I attached the screenshot of linked service I created. My question is WHEN THERE IS AN OPTION TO USE MANAGED IDENTITY, WHY MS MADE FUNCTION APP KEY MANDATORY FIELD HERE. My question is purely on the feature MS is providing.